# Check for Errors: Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, grouping

I got a query, where I want to check if there is ANY error for a specific Number (No). If there is 1 or more errors, the result should be "yes". If there is no error, the result should be "no". But I want only 1 line per No, not multiple lines.

See the below query and the result I want it to be:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUB1.ItemNo) != 1 THEN 'ERROR: ItemNo not numeric'
           ELSE 'OK'
       END AS ErrorType, SUB1.No
FROM
(
--123
    SELECT 123 AS No, '123456789' AS ItemNo
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 123 AS No, '123456789x' AS ItemNo
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 123 AS No, '122456789' AS ItemNo
    UNION ALL
--456
    SELECT 456 AS No, '123456789' AS ItemNo
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 456 AS No, '178978788' AS ItemNo
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 456 AS No, '114147787' AS ItemNo
) AS SUB1
```

--Result: How it should look in the end

```
SELECT 'Yes' AS Error, 123 AS No
UNION ALL
SELECT 'No' AS Error, 456 AS No
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use aggregation:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN MIN(ISNUMERIC(SUB1.ItemNo)) = 0 THEN 'ERROR: ItemNo not numeric'
             ELSE 'OK'
        END) AS ErrorType,
       SUB1.No
FROM (SELECT 123 AS No, '123456789' AS ItemNo
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 123 AS No, '123456789x' AS ItemNo
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 123 AS No, '122456789' AS ItemNo
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 456 AS No, '123456789' AS ItemNo
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 456 AS No, '178978788' AS ItemNo
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 456 AS No, '114147787' AS ItemNo
     ) SUB1
GROUP BY SUB1.NO;
```

In this context, the `MIN()` just checks if any values are not numeric.